# How to add two list entries into a CSV file each under different headings?

Tags: python

If I have two lists in python for example...

```
titles = [
    'April',
    'Apple',
    'Donkey'
]

texts = [
    'April description text...',
    'Apple description text...',
    'Donkey description text...'
]
```

How can I create a loop that runs through the `titles` and adds them to a `csv` file with there corresponding `texts` elements?
I have this script bellow to create a `csv` file but not sure how to add the lists...

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['TITLES', 'TEXT']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```

In theory this [image: CSV file example] is what I would like the final product to look like...bearing in mind that the actual lists will have over `100` entries in it so I can't really do this manually, that is why I need a python script to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing the values of a `dict` to the csv, so you don't have to use `Dictwriter`. Also you can use `zip` to go through both lists at the same time.

```
import csv

titles = [
    'April',
    'Apple',
    'Donkey'
]

texts = [
    'April description text...',
    'Apple description text...',
    'Donkey description text...'
]

with open('test1.csv', mode='w',newline="") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['TITLES', 'TEXT'])
    for x in zip(titles,texts):
        writer.writerow(x)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me however I did have to remove `,newline=""` because of an error about it being an invalid argument, but as far as I can tell it has fixed my problems, thank you.